# python find string pattern in numpy array of strings

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a numpy array of strings 'A' of length 100 and they are sentences of different sizes. It is string NOT numpy strings

```
>>> type(A[0])
<type 'str'>
```

I want to find the location of strings in A which contain certain pattern like 'zzz' in them.

I tried

```
np.core.defchararray.find(A, 'zzz')
```

gives error:

```
TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

I assume I will need to change each of the 'str' in A to numpy string ?

Edit:

I want to find the index of 'zzz' appearance in A

Comment: What do you want to do when you find them?  Split them?  Get the index?

Comment: Why not just `[s.find(pattern) for s in A]` and then you will have the index of the first occurrence of that pattern in each string (-1 if the pattern is not found)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to be fancy with this, you can get the list of indicies with a list comprehension and the `in` operator:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = ["aaa","aazzz","zzz"]
>>> n = np.array(lst)
>>> [i for i,item in enumerate(n) if "zzz" in item]
[1, 2]
```

Note that here the elements of the array are actually numpy strings, but the `in` operator will work for regular strings too, so it's moot.

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is the nature of your array of strings.

If I make the array like:

```
In [362]: x=np.array(['one','two','three'])

In [363]: x
Out[363]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three'], 
      dtype='<U5')

In [364]: type(x[0])
Out[364]: numpy.str_
```

The elements are special kind of string, implicitly padded to 5 characters (the longest, 'np.char methods work on this kind of array

```
In [365]: np.char.find(x,'one')
Out[365]: array([ 0, -1, -1])
```

But if I make a object array that contains strings, it produces your error

```
In [366]: y=np.array(['one','two','three'],dtype=object)

In [367]: y
Out[367]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)

In [368]: type(y[0])
Out[368]: str

In [369]: np.char.find(y,'one')
...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/defchararray.py in find(a, sub, start, end)
...
TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

And more often than not, an object array has to be treated as a list.

```
In [370]: y
Out[370]: array(['one', 'two', 'three'], dtype=object)

In [371]: [i.find('one') for i in y]
Out[371]: [0, -1, -1]

In [372]: np.array([i.find('one') for i in y])
Out[372]: array([ 0, -1, -1])
```

The `np.char` methods are convenient, but they aren't faster.  They still have to iterate through the array applying regular string operations to each element.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
np.core.defchararray.find(A.astype(str), 'zzz')
```